# How to run a .sql file using bcp in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, bcp

I am new to handling SQL Server bulk export. I have a batch file in which I have written some code to execute specific .sql files at regular intervals and save the output into an excel sheet. I have done this using sqlcmd. I want to use bcp to do the same. Any help on this issue is much appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to change from `sqlcmd` to `bcp`?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-2017 .. check this. use -i option to provide input file

Comment: @Alejandro bcp is made specifically for import/export bulk data and it's very fast compared to sqlcmd.

Comment: need to pump out tab separated data'

Comment: @UdItSolanki, the BCP command does not seem to be recognising the sql in the input file. It only accepts a direct sql string. -i is for input file, which is basically an interface file for interactive BCP usage, You can put sequential responses in this file. Not the SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use -s "|" with sqlcmd. That should allow you to out-put the data with fields separated by a tab.

-s is for column separator.

See [sqlcmd Utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 0):

Hafsa Mushtaq.

The best option is powershell - you can use this awesome dbatools function to Import your data https://github.com/sqlcollaborative/dbatools/blob/development/functions/Import-DbaCsvToSql.ps1 and my script to Export https://github.com/ktaranov/sqlserver-kit/blob/master/PowerShell/Export-SQLTableToCSV.ps1

Or you can use dynamic sql to generate all statements and then execute it.
All stored procedures below needed to solve some limitation of bcp and BULK INSERT in SQL Server - bcp can not create files with header and BULK INSERT can not import in tables with IDENTITY column.

To unload all tables to csv using bcp utility and my stored procedures [`usp_bcpTableUnload`](https://github.com/ktaranov/sqlserver-kit/blob/master/Stored_Procedure/usp_bcpTableUnload.sql) and [`usp_PrintString`](https://github.com/ktaranov/sqlserver-kit/blob/master/Stored_Procedure/sp_PrintString.sql):

```
DECLARE @tsqlCommand NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';
DECLARE @path NVARCHAR(900) = 'd:\111\NIIGAZ\333\';
DECLARE @databaseName  SYSNAME = 'NIIGAZ';
DECLARE @exludeColumns NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';  -- '[CreatedDate],[ModifiedDate],[UserID]';
DECLARE @codePage NVARCHAR(10) ='C65001';  -- '1251'
DECLARE @crlf NVARCHAR(10) = CHAR(13);
DECLARE @debug BIT = 1;

IF @debug = 0 SET NOCOUNT ON;


SELECT @tsqlCommand = @tsqlCommand + 'EXECUTE dbo.usp_bcpTableUnload @databaseName   = ''' + @databaseName + ''','              + @crlf +
                                     '                               @path           = ''' + @path + ''','                      + @crlf + 
                                     '                               @schemaName     = ''' + SCHEMA_NAME(t.[schema_id]) + ''',' + @crlf +
                                     '                               @tableName      = ''' + t.[name]        + ''','            + @crlf +
                                     '                               @excludeColumns = ''' + @exludeColumns  + ''','            + @crlf +
                                     '                               @codePage       = ''' + @codePage       + ''','            + @crlf +
                                     '                               @formatFile     = ''xml'';'                                + @crlf
FROM [sys].[tables] t
INNER JOIN [sys].[dm_db_partition_stats] ps
     ON ps.[object_id] = t.[object_id]
WHERE [index_id] < 2  -- AND SCHEMA_NAME(t.[schema_id]) IN ()
GROUP BY t.[name]
        ,t.[schema_id]
HAVING SUM(ps.[row_count]) > 1
--ORDER BY 1, 2 ASC
OPTION (RECOMPILE);

IF @debug = 1
BEGIN
    EXEC dbo.usp_PrintString @str = @tsqlCommand;
END;

IF @debug = 0
BEGIN
EXEC sp_executesql @tsqlCommand;
END
```

And to bulk insert this files in database you can use this code and stored procedure [`usp_BulkUpload`](https://github.com/ktaranov/sqlserver-kit/blob/master/Stored_Procedure/usp_BulkUpload.sql):

```
DECLARE @debug BIT = 0;
DECLARE @tsqlCommand NVARCHAR(max) = '';
DECLARE @path NVARCHAR(1000) = '$(varPath)txt\';  -- 'd:\NII\SQL\txt\';
DECLARE @ExcludeColumns NVARCHAR(1000) = '';  -- 'CreatedDate,ModifiedDate,UserID';
DECLARE @firstRow INTEGER = 2;
DECLARE @fieldTerminator NVARCHAR(10) = '''|''';
DECLARE @crlf NVARCHAR(10) = CHAR(13);

WITH fk_tables AS (
SELECT  s1.name AS from_schema
      , o1.name AS from_table
      , s2.name AS to_schema
      , o2.name AS to_table
FROM sys.foreign_keys fk
INNER JOIN sys.objects o1 ON fk.parent_object_id = o1.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.schemas s1 ON o1.schema_id = s1.schema_id
INNER JOIN sys.objects o2 ON fk.referenced_object_id = o2.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.schemas s2 ON o2.schema_id = s2.schema_id
/*For the purposes of finding dependency hierarchy
    we're not worried about self-referencing tables*/
WHERE NOT (s1.name = s2.name
       AND o1.name = o2.name
  )
)
, ordered_tables AS (
SELECT   s.name AS schemaName
       , t.name AS tableName
       , 0 AS table_level
FROM sys.tables AS t
INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
LEFT JOIN fk_tables fk ON s.name = fk.from_schema
 AND t.name = fk.from_table
WHERE fk.from_schema IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT fk.from_schema
 ,fk.from_table
 ,ot.table_level + 1
FROM fk_tables fk
INNER JOIN ordered_tables ot ON fk.to_schema = ot.schemaName
 AND fk.to_table = ot.tableName
)
,final AS (
SELECT DISTINCT ot.schemaName
 ,ot.tableName
 ,ot.table_level
FROM ordered_tables ot
INNER JOIN (
 SELECT schemaName
  ,tableName
  ,MAX(table_level) maxLevel
 FROM ordered_tables
 GROUP BY schemaName
  ,tableName
 ) mx ON ot.schemaName = mx.schemaName
 AND ot.tableName = mx.tableName
 AND mx.maxLevel = ot.table_level
)
SELECT @tsqlCommand = @tsqlCommand +
      'EXECUTE     dbo.usp_BulkUpload @path            = ''' + @path + ''', '                  + @crlf +
      '                               @fileName        = ''' + QUOTENAME(final.schemaName) + '.' + QUOTENAME(final.tableName) + ''', ' + @crlf +
      '                               @fileExtension   = ''txt'', '                            + @crlf +
      '                               @databaseName    = ''NIIGAZ'', '                         + @crlf +
      '                               @schemaName      = ''' + final.schemaName + ''', '       + @crlf +
      '                               @tableName       = ''' + final.tableName + ''', '        + @crlf +
      '                               @FIRSTROW        = ' + CAST(@firstRow AS NVARCHAR) + ',' + @crlf +
      '                               @CODEPAGE        = ' + N'65001' + ' ,'                        + @crlf +
      '                               @useIdentity     = ' + CASE WHEN OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(schemaName + '.' + tableName), 'TableHasIdentity') = 1
                                                                  THEN '1' ELSE '0'
                                                             END + ' ,'                        + @crlf +
      '                               @FIELDTERMINATOR = ' + @fieldTerminator + ',' + @crlf +
      '                               @ROWTERMINATOR   = ''' + CASE WHEN final.tableName IN ('PowerPlant', 'Turbine', 'EnergoBusinessArticle') THEN N'0x0a'''
                                                                ELSE '\n'''
                                                           END + ' ,'            + @crlf +
      '                               @excludeColumns  = ''' + @ExcludeColumns + ''';'         + @crlf
  FROM final
 WHERE (
           final.schemaName NOT IN ('dbo')
           AND final.tableName NOT IN (
                 'ExcludeYourTable'
           )
           AND final.tableName NOT LIKE '%Temp'
      )
      OR final.tableName IN ('IncludeYourTable')
      OR final.tableName LIKE 'AspNet%'
      OR final.tableName LIKE 'Application%'
ORDER BY table_level;

IF @debug = 1 EXECUTE dbo.usp_PrintString @str = @tsqlCommand;
IF @debug = 0 EXECUTE sp_executesql @tsqlCommand;
```